# Resolve many proguard warning

Tags: java, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, proguard

I saw a lot of warnings when connected, more than 5 thousand, I found information that I should solve problems in a similar way

`-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**`

But I have too many classes, I do not believe what I need to add all this one by one, it will take a lot of time and nerves

What are possible solutions? Maybe it can be simplified

I have more than 5 thousand such warnings

`1>PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzal: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
1>PROGUARD : warning : android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap: can't find referenced class android.support.annotation.RestrictTo$Scope
1>PROGUARD : warning : android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache: can't find referenced class android.support.annotation.Nullable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually fix all warnings, by applying proguard rules.

Your program code contains copies or better versions of Android runtime classes in the package com.google.android.gms If that's ok:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.**
```

And so on...

ProGuard manual > [Troubleshooting](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting)

Comment: The answer is Yes, Actually there are many plug-ins for generating proguard like "AndroidProguard", but they paste a pre-fixed proguard file to your application.

Comment: Сan you tell me how i can generate this file in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't know whether "AndroidProguard" available in a visul studio or not. Here's Android Studio Link https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10016-androidproguard